# Rails: Form not saving to db, but create method returns true when submitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a simple blog setup with resource routing which authenticates a user before allowing them to view blogs. I am able to "signup" by entering data through the "rails c" but when trying to submit a form it does not save to db and the "create" method returns true as if it did save.

> Controller: blogs_controller.rb

```
class BlogsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :confirm_logged_in, :except => [:login, :attempt_login, :new, :logout]

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end


  def create
  @user = User.new(message_params)
    if @user.save!
      redirect_to(:action => 'login')
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end


  def login
  end


  def attempt_login
    if params[:email].present? && params[:password].present?
      found_user = User.where(:email => params[:email]).first
      if found_user
        authorized_user = found_user.authenticate(params[:password])
      end
    end
    if authorized_user
      session[:user_id] = authorized_user.id
      session[:email] = authorized_user.email
      redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    else
      redirect_to(:action => 'login')
    end
  end


  def index
  end

  def show_month
    @month_year = params[:month_year]
    @year = params[:year]
  end

  def show_category
    @category = params[:category]
  end

  def show_page
    @date = params[:date]
  end

  def logout
    session[:user_id] = nil
    session[:email] = nil
    flash[:notice] = "Logged out."
    redirect_to(:action => "login" )
  end


    private
  def message_params
    return params.require(:user).permit( :email, :password )
  end

  def confirm_logged_in
    unless session[:user_id]
      flash[:notice] = "Please login"
      redirect_to(:action => 'login')
      return false
    else
      return true
    end
  end

end
```

> Signup: new.html.erb

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <%= form_for @user, url: blogs_path(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email, :required => true %>
      <br>
      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, :required => true %>
      <br>
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :required => true %>
      <br>
      <%= f.submit("Submit")%>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Model: user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
end
```

> Schema: schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20151026022639) do

  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "messages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "phone_number"
    t.string   "user_message"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
  end

end
```

> Server logs: params

```
Started POST "/attempt_login" for ::1 at 2015-10-26 02:57:57 -0400
Processing by BlogsController#attempt_login as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"z4NgU41NLizqUE5vgXc44Q5n6VG36ho+5TVcPB4ixB7grZnCuwJY64+EWFzFIIJShbHEBNk3JutBuO4oalV2gQ==", "email"=>"chrispelnar@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Login"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["email", "chrispelnar@gmail.com"]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/blog_login
Completed 302 Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

> Routes routes.rb

```
  get '/blog_signup'           => 'blogs#new'
  post 'blog_signup'           => 'blogs#create'
  get '/blog_login'            => 'blogs#login'
  post 'attempt_login'         => 'blogs#attempt_login'
  get '/blogs_home'            => 'blogs#index'
  get '/blog_month_archive'    => 'blogs#show_month'
  get '/blog_category_archive' => 'blogs#show_category'
  get '/blog_page'             => 'blogs#show_page'
  get '/logout'                => 'blogs#logout'
```

Comment: Can you post the `params` that are generated in the server log in the question while submitting the form?

Comment: I have updated with the server logs

Comment: why are you updating/creating users via blogsController??

Comment: I know, you're right. I am going to create a users_controller. I can see that if I would have done that in the first place I would have not run into this issue at all.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of fixes to be made - here's what I'd recommend:

```
#config/routes.rb
root "posts#index"
resources :posts, only: [:index, :show]

resources :users, only: [:new, :create], path: "", path_names: { new: "signup", create: "signup" }
resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy], path: "", path_names: { new: "login", create: "login", destroy: "logout" }
```

This splits up your controllers into different actions.

This might seem complicated, but trust me, it's going to be MUCH BETTER for your application in the long run.

---

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   #put all your application-centric logic here
   before_action :confirm_logged_in

   private

   def confirm_logged_in
      #don't need to "return" anything here
      redirect_to new_sessions_path, notice: "Please login" unless session[:user_id]
   end
end
```

Instead of "blogs", call it "posts". Your application logic stays in the application controller:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @posts = Post.all
   end

   def show
      @post = Post.find params[:id]
   end
end
```

This is to handle user sessions (logins) (stole this [form Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb)):

```
#app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_action :confirm_logged_in

    def new
    end

    def create
        if params[:email].present? && params[:password].present?
          if User.exists? email: params[:email]
               authorized_user = found_user.authenticate params[:password]
          end
        end
        if authorized_user
             session[:user_id] = authorized_user.id
             session[:email] = authorized_user.email
             redirect_to root_path, notice: "Successful Login"
        else
             redirect_to :new, notice: "Sorry, there was an error"
        end 
    end

    def destroy
        session.delete(:user_id)
        session.delete(:email)
        redirect_to new_sessions_path, notice: "Logged Out"
    end

end
```

---

> I am able to "signup" by entering data through the "rails c" but when trying to submit a form it does not save to db

Here's how it should be done:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @user = User.new
   end

   def create
      @user = User.new user_params
      @user.save
   end

   private

   def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :other, :params)
   end
end
```

You'll then be able to use the following view:

```
#app/views/users/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.email_field :email %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

--

As an aside, you'd benefit profusely from using the [`Devise` gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).

This will basically take out all of the `session` functionality from your app, including it in `Devise`. This works really well and I would *highly* recommend it.

Comment: Thanks Rich. I ended up making another controller called users_controller.rb and moved all of the logic into there to avoid conflict. Everything is currently running smoothly. I have used Devise before but wanted to craft the signup/login portion by hand to learn more of the logic behind it.

Comment: Nice going, good to hear someone with some competancy giving things a go themselves rather than expecting others to do it all for them :D

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
private
def message_params
  params.require(:user).permit( :email, :password, :password_confirmation )
end
```

Comment: I tried this expamle but it did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem was in the controller:

```
before_action :confirm_logged_in, :except => [:login, :attempt_login, :new, :logout]
```

> I was missing ":create", this resolved the issue:

```
before_action :confirm_logged_in, :except => [:login, :attempt_login, :new, :logout, :create]
```